# Filtering data in GridView in .net2.0

Tags: .net, gridview, .net-2.0

I have a page that uses GridView to display some data taken from a stored procedure

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString1 %>"
            SelectCommand="p_get_all_students" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

One of the columns returned is **studyYear** with the possible values: 1,2,3

I would like to add a set of 3 checkboxes to allow filtering of the displayed results by the **studyYear**

How could I do this?

<strike>Ideally I would like to keep the stored procedure as p_get_all_students and only filter the displayed information - so there would be only one initial call to the database.</strike>

**EDIT** 
The number of rows returned by the stored procedure is from 20 to 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally change the way the app was architected. If you want to keep the code the same though, you could hook into the RowDataBound event.

Update- [here's an example which should help you](http://forums.asp.net/p/1357949/2793169.aspx#2793169).

Comment: +1 Thanks Richard. that solution worked but only partially. All the rows would become visible after sorting and also hiding some of the rows was messing up the numbering - I will probably change the design so the sp takes the parameter